# HTML/CSS hover background image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with putting an img for hover background.

It should look like this : [Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptAdK.jpg)

These 2 lines, represent the hover transparent image, and the text "home" should be in center of that img.. I have no idea how to do that... Anyone ?

Sorry if my english is bad

```css
.page-container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}


nav {
    height: 136px;
    
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 70px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;

}


nav li a {
    margin-right: 165px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: font91477;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    background-size: 75px;
 

}

a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9E9E9E;
}

a:hover {
    height: 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/P5tF09r.png) no-repeat center;

    
  
}
```

```html
    
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
        </div>
        
        <nav>
            <div class="page-container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">O Podjetju</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Produkti</a></li>
                    <li><a class="last-child" href="#">Kontakti</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: you have to post code to get answers here

Comment: Here is a general solution on how to use an image with hover. https://jsfiddle.net/jzeo1ns6/

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please share code and put the image directly inside the post, link can brake.

Comment: okey, i post a part of my code, idk if that is ok ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
just add the following css styles 

a:hover {
    height: 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/P5tF09r.png) no-repeat center;
    /*****************here they are ************/
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;


}
```

Comment: Okey, that hepls, but there is still a problem, now i need that my text stay where it was before ... i hope that you understand me :D                                http://i.imgur.com/EQo34mP.png

Comment: try this modifying this code :-
nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
 height: 75px;
}
nav li a {
    margin-right: 165px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: font91477;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    background-size: 75px;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
a{
 height: 100%;
}

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex Flex has some know issues and it's supported by IE only for v11...

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't make it in css ? Something like this

```css
.menu{
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__item{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__item a{
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__item::after{
  content:'';
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.menu__item:hover::after{
  width: 50px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item"><a>Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a>test</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a>very long title for test</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a>test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: okeey, that's cool... i will consider about this solution :) thanks